# Caching Imager using UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER

Tags: android, universal-image-loader, image-caching

I am trying to cache image using universal image loader

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheOnDisk(true).cacheInMemory(true).imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .displayer(new BitmapDisplayer(100)).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();

ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions).memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .diskCacheSize(10 * 1024 * 1024).build();

ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

for display images

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUrl, imageview,defaultOptions);
```

now I can come to know that images are loading from cache or from url ?

Comment: it's loading from url. if you load from cache you also add some mathod....

Comment: if think if you have internet connection it will load from url and if else it will show the cache

Comment: i want to load from cache even if net is present . only 1st time load from net then from cache

Answer (score 1):

you can check using following method

```
MemoryCacheUtils.findCachedBitmapsForImageUri(imageUri, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());
```

This will let you know about this

Answer (score 0):

You can add `config.writeDebugLogs();` to your Universal Image Loader config

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder config = new    ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context);
        config.threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2);
        config.denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory();
        config.diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator());
        config.diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024); // 50 MiB
        config.tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO);
        config.writeDebugLogs(); // Remove for release app

        // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config.build());
```

Then when you load image, check the **logcat** to know that image is loading from cache or from url

Comment: it showing Start display image task [https://url_45*40]
   Load image from disk cache [https://url_45*40] .. so it taking from cache ?

Comment: when you cache image then this image can loaded without internet. and if you don't cache, everytime you load image, you need to connect to internet. Depend on your purpose, you should choose cache or not cache

Comment: what is difference in disk cache and memory ? .cacheOnDisk(true).cacheInMemory(false) is good ?